# Creating default object from empty value laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've been getting the error `Creating default object from empty value laravel`I was successful to insert new rows with the following code but today when I tried testing the code it is returning the error pointing on the line `$reviw->rating = $request->productrating;`.

Structure of my db table is:

`id|fname|lname|email|country|title|content|rating|thumbnail|tour_id|status`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $this->validate($request, [
        'fname'     => 'required',
        'lname'     =>  'required',
        'email'     => 'required',
        'country'   => 'required',
        'title'   => 'required|min:10',
        'productrating' => 'required',
        'content'   => 'required|min:10'
        ]);        
    // dd($request->productrating);
    $review = new Review;
    $review->fname = $request->fname;
    $review->lname = $request->lname;
    $review->email = $request->email;
    $review->country = $request->country;
    $review->title = $request->title;
    $review->content = $request->content;        
    $reviw->rating = $request->productrating;
    if($request->hasFile('fileupload1')){
        $image = $request->file('fileupload1');
        $filename = 'thumb'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = 'images/client_review/'.$filename;
        Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->save($location);
        $review->thumbnail = $location;
    }
    $review->tour_id = $request->product_id;
    $review->status = false;
    $review->save();
    Session::flash('success','Thank You for submitting us your review.');
    return view('public.pages.message-review');        
}
```

I'm sending following data from the form to save into the table.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in `$reviw->rating = $request->productrating;` change `$reviw` to `$review` and it will work

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to update your code like :

```
    $review = new Review;
    $review->fname = $request->fname;
    $review->lname = $request->lname;
    $review->email = $request->email;
    $review->country = $request->country;
    $review->title = $request->title;
    $review->content = $request->content;        
    $review->rating = $request->productrating;
```